# Rsync: Is it possible to transmit src files as symlinks and copying rest of dir structure

Tags: rsync, symlink

I want to copy the src dir as a template i.e. preserving the same structure. The files in this template dir should point to src directory as symlinks. I am not sure if rsync can do this out of box.

Answer (score 7):

Rsync can only do copies or (sometimes) hard links, not symbolic links. The `cp` program from GNU coreutils can do what you want, at least if you don't need fancy rsync options such as filtering based on file names. Just use the `-s` flag, plus `-a` for recursion.

```
cp -as source target
```

If you need filtering, you can use [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/zsh)'s [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). The `zmv` function moves files by default, but you can specify another operation with `-S` (create symlinks, but this isn't good for your use case because it doesn't copy directories) or `-p` (specify an arbitrary program, here I use a function that creates any needed directories and then makes a symlink). You can specify a [pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) to restrict which files get copied; here I use `^*.dontcopy` to omit files with the extension `.dontcopy` and `(m-7)` to only process files modified within the last 7 days, plus `^/` to omit directories from the list of files to process.

```
mkdir_ln () {
  mkdir -p -- $2:t &&
  ln -s -- $1:A $2
}
cd source
zmv -P mkdir_ln -Q '**/^*.dontcopy(m-7^/)' '../target/$f'
```

Above I use the [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) `(:A)` to turn the first argument into an absolute path. If you want to create relative symlinks, you'll have to construct the proper target path, with the right number of `../` components.

```
mkdir_ln () {
  mkdir -p -- $2:t &&
  ln -s -- ${1//[^/]##/..}/$1 $2
}
```

Comment: I think your `zmv` needs `-P` instead of `-p`; otherwise it passes `--` as the first argument to `mkdir_ln`